# One to One relation in Entity frame work Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have 2 tables, Users and Employees

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
 [UserID] [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 [Username] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
 [Activo] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [UltimoAcesso] [datetime] NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [ColaboradorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL

    PRIMARY KEY(ColaboradorID),
    UNIQUE (UserID)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_UtilizadorID] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I'm using Entity FrameWork Database first.

I'm trying to insert a new user

```
 public void fvAddUser_InsertItem()
        {
            var item = new InventarioCiclico.Users();
            using (InventarioCiclicoContext db = new InventarioCiclicoContext())
            {
                Employee c = new Employee ();

            c.Nome = (fvAddUser.FindControl("txtNome") as TextBox).Text;
            c.Email = (fvAddUser.FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text;
            item.Employee.Add(c);

            var employee = db.Set<Employee>();

            TryUpdateModel(item);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (db.Users.Any(u => u.Username == item.Username))
                {
                    // Handle exception
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Users.Add(item);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     var userID = item.UserID;
                    c.UserID = userID;
                    employee.Add(c);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

However it keeps giving me exception of violation of unique value? Before starting with entity framework I would insert on Users table first, get scope_identity and insert on Employee table after and I'm trying to do this using EF6 but i don't know what can i do about this.

Comment: Why are adding the employee twice? 1. `item.Employee.Add(c);` 2. `employee.Add(c);`

Comment: because i'm still new using EF and i thought i had to add it to the item first and finally insert from the context

Comment: when you call the SaveChanges(), the 2 entities are being already saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding two employees with the same `UserId` in the database and since `UserId` is a unique field in employee table you are getting the exception of violation of unique value.
In the line `item.Employee.Add(c);` you are add the employee to the user, therefore, when adding the user to the database, the employee will be added two. So you don't need the last three lines:

```
 c.UserID = userID;
 employee.Add(c);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. Wasn't sure how to insert into a table that depended on another in here.